# Second Eclipse plugin project seems to be interfered with by first -- why?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I created a plugin project using the Eclipse wizard, wrote a little code and then created a second project without any change. When I run the second project so that it creates an instance of Eclipse for testing, I see the behavior of the first project. I am guessing that both projects share some directories or something. Can it be explained what is happening and how to create two plugin projects in same workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any number of plugins in a workspace, one of mine has 52.

Note that when you test a plugin using 'Run As > Eclipse Application' Eclipse normally includes all the plugins in the workspace in the run. So you would get both your plugins included.

If you don't want both plugins included go to 'Run > Run Configurations' and edit the plugins list in the run configuration. You can duplicate run configurations to create as many different setups as you need.

Comment: Thanks, that is what must be happening. I assumed that Run As > .. ran the specific plugin.